# My image is not loading in image view in json volley method

Tags: android, json, imageview, android-volley

my adapter file.java  I have using `JSON` volley method. Image is not load the image view how to solve this problem?

**Jason image format;**

```
"image":[  
   "151660038947843.png",
   "151660038916249.png"
],
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) 
{
    final Hostel hostel = hostelList.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(hostel.getName());
    holder.mobile1.setText( hostel.getMobile1() );
    holder.mobile2.setText( hostel.getMobile2() );
    holder.address.setText( hostel.getAddress() );
    holder.place.setText( hostel.getPlace() );

    Glide.with(mContext).load(hostel.getImage()).into(holder.image);
}
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
if(!(1 <= distance)){
    jsonName = jsonObject.getString("pname");                            
    jsonMobile1 = jsonObject.getString("price");
    jsonMobile2=jsonObject.getString( "discount" );
    jsonAddress=jsonObject.getString("pdescription");
    jsonArea=jsonObject.getString( "area" );                             
    JSONArray jsonImage = jsonObject.getJSONArray("image");
    jsonPhoto = jsonImage.getString(0);
    Hostel hostel=new Hostel(jsonPhoto, jsonName,jsonMobile1,jsonMobile2,jsonAddress,jsonArea );
    hostelList.add(hostel);
}
```

Comment: `hostel.getImage()`. Please tell the value. Now it is unclear which url you give to Glide. Further it is pretty unclear if there are image files. And where are they? On the device? Do they have to be downloaded? You told nothing. You only showed some image names.

Comment: I am uploading image in json file.jpg format

Comment: there should be complete url to load the image not the image name.

Comment: the image path dosn't describe the full home of your image you should provide full path @NmSankar

Comment: how to provide the full path.any example

Comment: for example  urlofserver/folder/151660038947843.png and if you past it in browser the image should appear...@NmSankar

Comment: send your mail id... I will sent in my code

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an url or path of the image in your json response. You just cant give `<ImageName>.png` as an input.

Comment: which place this url placed

Comment: your hostel.getImage() should return the url or path of the image.
You should proceed like hostel.setImage(" <url or path>") while forming the hostel object